# Does rooting phone wipe your data if the bootloader is unlocked?

Tags: root-access, motorola-moto-g2

A few months ago I reset my phone because it had began to break and get really laggy. I want to re-root it now, I was just wondering if it would reset my data if the bootloader is already unlocked?

Comment: Factory reset shouldn't unroot your phone.

Comment: No. A factory reset won't unroot your phone as a reset only affects the `/data` and `/cache` partitions, and root resides on the `/system` partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the G2 specifically, but in general, no, rooting a device on its own should not wipe data. Rooting your phone is the process of getting the `su` binary installed and available to access root privileges. That said, @SarpSTA is right in stating that a factory reset shouldn't unroot your phone. The `su` binary is placed in the system partition, which is left intact on wipe. If a wipe touched /system, your phone would be bricked and unusable, requiring a low-level flash to recover. What you may be missing is an app, such as SuperSU, to control access to root.

Answer (score -1):

You re-flashed your phone or just done "Factory Reset"?I think that it would not wipe your data if you root your phone in case that you re-flashed it, but if you just have done" Factory Reset " it have to be already rooted.

Comment: Clarification is required here.